# compiler error I've never seen could someone help me understand it?

Tags: c++

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "KeyValue::KeyValue()", referenced from:
      Mapper::map() in Mapper.o
  "KeyValueList::KeyValueList()", referenced from:
      QuickSort::group() in QuickSort.o
  "KeyValueList::~KeyValueList()", referenced from:
      QuickSort::group() in QuickSort.o
      std::vector<KeyValueList, std::allocator<KeyValueList> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<KeyValueList*, std::vector<KeyValueList, std::allocator<KeyValueList> > >, KeyValueList const&) in QuickSort.o
      void std::_Destroy<KeyValueList>(KeyValueList*) in QuickSort.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There's no other error in my code, I have 1 warning saying:

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'
```

which I don't think would cause a linking error... Could someone help me understand what this error is and how it may have happened?

I can provide some code if needed.

Comment: Please show the definition of the class `KeyValue`.  There are several common mistakes that can cause this syndrome, but I can't tell you which one it is without seeing some of your code.

Comment: These are _linker_ errors, not compiler errors.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to implement those functions. Maybe you forgot to link the relevant .obj into your executable. Maybe something else. To find out, delete bits of your program until either A) you fix it, or B) you have a small enough program to copy-paste here. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob Yeah it was a stupid mistake. I just forgot to define my constructor and destructor for those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to link to some code that doesn't exist; or certainly not for x86_64. Where is `KeyValue()` defined ? - link to that.

You probably included the header file for KeyValue in Mapper and Quicksort but didn't add the source for the compiler to deal with.

Comment: Yeah that was it... I forgot to define my constructors and destructors... silly me, lol. I never saw a linker error before so I was confused.

Comment: Error messages about linking are usually a lot less detailed than compiler error messages so it's definitely worth spending time to study them.